# JMeter While controller in Loop controller for retries

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I have a While controller and a soap/xml-rpc request inside of it. I need to try to send this request for several times in case it doesn't work the first time, but start new thread if there are too many retries.

As I understand there must be Loop controller.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

If click on your thread group and go to "Add" and then "Logic Controller" you will see a bunch of loop options.

One option is to select while, set the condition to something like ${__javaScript("$deployed) != "yes";)}

So the while controller will loop until the $deployed var is set to "yes"

There are also a number of approaches to starting the next thread, but I could use some more detail on what you are trying to do..

Comment: There is a request that returns code 200 because process in system need time to be executed.
I want to check this request for several times(3-4) then start next thread if it is still returning code 200. Or stop resending this request once it worked without error